# Dynamics CRM with empty ChangedData rows

Tags: dynamics-crm

As a DBA, I'm studying a little more about our Dynamics CRM and I could see that our auditbase is 160GB.

Inside there's a column called "changedData" and in a lot of them, the row is empty.

1. Can I create, lets say, an automatic job running a "delete from auditbase where changedData =''"? Is this going to be a problem by not doing it via CRM?
2. Why is this rows apearing? I could not find this question on the internet, as every site have a different answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly running DML query in CRM database is unsupported and not recommended.

If this empty rows are bothering you, then I would recommend you to look into the source issue - which could be plugin code. I researched sometime back and documented in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450668/7920473) for possible reasons, that should give you some clue.

Comment: Thank you again Arun. I'm really curious about CRM. for 6 years I was focused only on SQL Server and other databases but , damm crm is relaly cool!

Comment: @RacerSQL happy to help. If my linked answer helps you, pls upvote them too :)